# How to implement ViewHolder using sealed class in Kotlin

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, kotlin, sealed

I saw an interesting viewholder implementation in this tweet https://twitter.com/AndroidDev/status/972502799496790018

```
override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: SealedAdapterViewHolder, position: Int) {
  return when (holder) {
    is HeaderHolder -> holder.displayHeader(items[position])
    is DetailsHolder -> holder.displayDetails(items[position])
  }
}
```

Unfortunately i can't figure out how to implement thouse holders. And I didn't find any examples of this trick.

In my viewholders I have to extend RecyclerView.ViewHolder and I have to extend sealed class so i can use it in "when clauses". Multiple inharitance is not allowed.

So is it possible and if it is then how?

P.S.

original authors write this:

> You can also use sealed classes in a RecyclerView adapter. They’re a
>   perfect fit for ViewHolders - with a clean set of types to dispatch
>   explicitly to each holder. Used as an expression, the compiler will
>   error if all types aren’t matched.

Comment: maybe like [this](https://medium.com/@paulnunezm/simpler-multiple-click-listeners-with-kotlin-sealed-classes-72a8f6e83e8)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Something like this:

```
sealed class SealedAdapterViewHolder(itemView: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView) {

    class HeaderHolder(view: View) : SealedAdapterViewHolder(view)

    class DetailsHolder(view: View) : SealedAdapterViewHolder(view)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

it's in the first post of the thread.

```
fun foo(holder : SealedAdapterViewHolder){
    when (holder) {
       is HeaderHolder -> holder.displayHeader(items[position])
       is DetailsHolder -> holder.displayDetails(items[position])
    }
}

sealed class SealedAdapterViewHolder(view: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(view)
data class HeaderHolder(val view: View): SealedAdapterViewHolder(view){
    fun displayHeader(...){}
}
data class DetailsHolder(val view: View): SealedAdapterViewHolder(view){
    fun displayDetails(...){}
}
```